# the solution of a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis

I have $y'+\frac{y}{(x+1)^2}=x^2y^2$ with $y(0)=1$.
I know exist local solution because $f(x,y)=-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}y+x^2y^2$ is $C^1(R\setminus\{-1\} \times R)$. It's a Bernoulli equation but when i put $z=y^{-1}$ as substitution I found an expression in which the integrable  is not calculable.It's right?

Comment: Mathematica gives a solution in terms of the function it calls `ExpIntegralEi`, defined by $z \mapsto -\int_{-z}^{\infty} e^{-t}/t \ \mathrm{d}t$. It can't find a neater closed form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the substitution $v = 1/y$, you get the linear d.e. 
$$ - v' + \frac{v}{(1+x)^2} =  x^2$$
whose general solution is
$$ v = e^{-1/(x+1)} \left( -\int x^2 e^{1/(x+1)} \; dx + C \right) $$
That integral is not elementary, but it can be expressed in terms of the [Exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) as
$$ \frac{2 x^3 + x^2 - 3 x - 2 }{6} e^{1/(x+1)} - \frac{\text{Ei}(1/(x+1))}{6}$$

Comment: Isn't the solution defined on all R?

Comment: The equation is not defined at $x=-1$.  The solution $v$ can be extended to be smooth on all $\mathbb R$, with $v(-1)=0$: of course this makes $y \to \infty$ there.